# WCF with singleton

Tags: c#, wcf, singleton

I'm tying to get some data from the form by singleton and send it via WCF:

WCF Library:

```
namespace ServerWcf
{
    public class MyWcf : IMyWcf
    {
        public int GetData()
        {
            return Singleton.form.GetSomeData();
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyWcf
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int GetData();
    }
}
```

Singleton:

```
public interface IGenerator
{
    int GetSomeData();
}

public class Singleton
{
    public static readonly Singleton Instance = new Singleton();

    public void Add(IGenerator generator)
    {
        form = generator;
    }

    public static IGenerator form;
}
```

And form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IGenerator
{
    //some fields and methods

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Singleton.Instance.Add(this);
    }

    public int GetSomeData()
    {
        return SomeDataFromForm;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Singleton.form.GetData());
    }
}
```

So, when I'm trying to call `GetData()` WCF function from another application (or even the same), I get this:

```
FaultException'1 is unhandled

object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

By searching internet i've found only responces like: "It's an error in your server code, keep debugging". But at the same time button1_Click works perfectly!

**So, the question is:** how's that even possible? My guess is that WCF library is trying to create a new instance of a `Singleton` class. Am I right? If so - how can I fix it?

P.S. WCF connection also works: if I change `GetData()` to something like

```
public int GetData()
{
    return 1;
}
```

it works perfectly.

The exact place of error is in autogenerated file Reference.cs. It looks like this:

```
public partial class MyWcfClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<WindowsFormsApplication1.Server.IMyWcf>, WindowsFormsApplication1.Server.IMyWcf {

        public MyWcfClient() {
        }

        public MyWcfClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public MyWcfClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public MyWcfClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public MyWcfClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public int GetData() 
        {
            return base.Channel.GetData();   //  <== The error occurs here 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your null reference exception occurring?

Comment: where do you declare and set value for this variable `SomeDataFromForm` ?

Comment: @scartag simplified, it is a value of TextBox inside this form, converted to int.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Added this info to the question.